# How to pull all year to date transactions from Quickbooks Online

Tags: python, pandas, quickbooks-online

I'm working on a budgeting application for internal use at my company. The application is in Python and I am using pandas to analyze our financial performance.

In order to work with the data, I need to pull ALL transactions year to date from our Quickbooks Online account. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Not familiar with quickbooks online, but are you able to download the transactions into a comma delimited file (csv)?

Comment: The [support homepage](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/pages/inproducthelp/core/qb2k12/contentpackage/thirdparty/excel/task_excel_export_trans.html?family=pro) says that you could export the data to csv. Assuming this is possible, you could import that csv-file using [pandas IO tools](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files) and process the data.

Comment: @albert, I'm doing that now, but I would like to use the API as opposed to automating through session automation with Mechanize or similar.

Answer (score 1):

For QBO, you will have to query on each transaction entity/endpoint using filter on start-date as the beginning of the year.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/querying_data

Comment: Thanks for the link Nimisha. 

Yes, querying on each transaction is prohibitive for mining many thousands of records. I'm really looking for a consistent API call that pulls a list of all Expenses over a date range.

I can export all expenses via the interface by navigating to Transactions > Expenses and then clicking Export to Excel. I can obviously automate the login process through session automation, but I was hoping there was an API call to do the same without depending on the interface.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. You can check CDC operation(change data capture) operation on developer.intuit.com but I guess that would not solve your purpose.